# SDP file for PCM audio stream?

Tags: multicast, rtp, sdp

I am multicasting PCM audio from `mpd` through pulseaudio to the network and receive it with `VLC`. This works fine as long as the audio is 44.1kHz - every other sampling rate results in VLC complaining it needs a correct `SDP` file describing the stream.

Is there a way to either
a) save the current "settings" in a running VLC session to a SDP file (to later edit it) or
b) create an SDP file by hand, which has these settings included:

```
rtp://@239.0.0.100:27028
24000Hz sampling rate
PCM Audio, 16bit
```

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what PulseAudio outputs with a debug level of 4 and works as the content of `test.sdp`:

```
v=0
o=root 3619500147 0 IN IP4 10.12.65.99
s=PulseAudio RTP Stream on RAMPv6
c=IN IP4 239.0.0.100
t=3619500147 0
a=recvonly
m=audio 27028 RTP/AVP 98
a=rtpmap:98 L16/24000/2
a=type:broadcast
```